# How do I make sure resources are injected in my configuration before it starts returning beans?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, annotations

I'm trying to define a bean which is a list of beans I've got configured using the @Component annotation. I'm using spring 3.1.

My @Configuration class looks like

```
@Configuration
public class ReferenceDataConfig {
    private ResourceA resourceA;

    @Resource
    private ResourceB resourceB;

    @Resource
    private ResourceC resourceC;

    @Resource
    private ResourceD resourceD;

    @Bean (name = "myResourceList")
    public List<MyResource> getResourceLst() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                resourceA
                , resourceB
                , resourceC
                , resourceD
        );
    }

    @Resource  (name = "resourceA")
    public void setResourceA(ResourceA resourceA) {
        this.resourceA = resourceA;
    }
```

What I'm finding is that the getResourceLst is getting called before any of the resources have been initialised. When I added the setResourceA method I can see that it does eventually get called, but by the time it's called it's too late. The myResourceList bean has already been created.

How should I deal with this problem?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible bug in Spring I think. I gather what I have should work, however the following workaround does the trick for me :

```
@Configuration
public class ReferenceDataConfig {
    @Bean (name = "myResourceList")
    public List<MyResource> getResourceLst(ResourceA resourceA, ResourceB resourceB, ResourceC resourceC, ResourceD resourceD) {
        return Arrays.asList(
                resourceA
                , resourceB
                , resourceC
                , resourceD
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, the solution may be simpler than you think.

If `List<MyResource>` is supposed to contain all beans of type `MyResource`, then you don't have to declare a separate bean for the list. You can just inject the list as you would inject any other bean and Spring will gather all beans of type `MyResource` that it finds in the application context and inject them all as a `List<MyResource>` object.

Comment: That could be useful at some point. However in this instance the order of the list matters.